# How to call a function from one Jupyter notebook to another in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to create a python pandas project in Visual Studio Code that consists of Jupyter notebooks. I would like to have a notebook where I store all my functions and be able to call them in other notebooks where I am exploring a specific dataset. How can I do that? If I am using Jupyter notebooks in the browser I would say %run .ipynb. However, this does not work in VS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only give you an abstract example because you didnt include any code examples.

Use the ipynb package/module importer. `pip install ipynb`

Create a notebook called master_functions.ipynb.

You can add all you functions here.

```
def master_function1(arg):
    print('hello', arg)

......
.....
.....

def master_function10(arg):
    pass
```

Then, create a second IPython Notebook and import this function with:

Now you can do this, which can import individual functions,

```
from ipynb.fs.full.master_functions import master_function1

master_function1('world') # prints hello world
```

You can also do this which imports master_functions as mf,

```
from ipynb.fs.full.master_functions as mf

mf.master_function1('world') # prints hello world
```

And this which imports all the functions from master_functions.ipydb

```
from ipynb.fs.full.master_functions import *

master_function1('world') # prints hello world
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `mf.master_function1('world')`

Comment: @rioV8 thanks i changed it